# Calc the corner of three coordinates

Tags: geometry

I am programming a Java application. In this application are three points, with random coordinates: point A, B and C. Further there are two lines: one line from A to B and a line from B to C. I want to know the corner (in degrees) of the line in point B.

I did a lot of research, but I didn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: What do you know? do you have variables initialized to tell us the coordinates? do we know the length of the line?

Comment: Represent point as Cartesian coordinate, calculate inner product of the BA and BC, then divide the length of BA and BC - and you get $\cos \theta$

Comment: @JohnLou The coordinates are random.

Comment: If you want the geometric angle, @YujieZha 's way is probably the most straightforward way. If you want an oriented angle you need to go further or do it another way.

Comment: I don't understand the way of Yujie Zha, can somebody write it in formula ?

Comment: The formulas for the inner product (or dot product) are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition). I presume you know how to find the vector between two coordinates and how to find a vector's magnitude?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a_x,a_y)$, $B=(b_x,b_y)$ and $C=(c_x,c_y)$. Then, you have to compute the angle between the following vectors:
$$(x_1,y_1) := \vec{BA} = (a_x-b_x,a_y-b_y),$$
$$(x_1,y_2) := \vec{BC} = (c_x-b_x,c_y-b_y).$$

To compute the angle in radians:

```
x1 = ax-bx
y1 = ay-by
x2 = cx-bx
y2 = cy-by
dot = x1*x2 + y1*y2
det = x1*y2 - y1*x2
angle = atan2(det, dot)
```

I hope you can follow from here.